# Transform a list into a list with greater or fewer items, maintaining the sum of list and relative difference between items

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list with 5 items

```
[6,4,2,4,6]
```

If I needed the list to be 10 items long, with the same sum and relative distribution it would look like

```
[3,3,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

That's simple because with double the number of items I just split each item in the previous list in half.

I'm trying to figure out a way make the first list any number of items long. Perhaps 3, 7, 12, 999...

Obviously it will very often not be possible to do it perfectly (as in the simple example), I'm trying to get to a solution that provides a best fit.

Comment: (1) Are you restricted to integer values?  (2) Do you care more about the distribution matching or the total sum matching?

Comment: I see I was ambiguous - 1) No non int is fine, 2) total sum must match, distribution as close as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of approaches that satisfy your specifications, depending what properties of the distribution you want to preserve.  One way would be to treat it as an interpolation problem and try to preserve the fraction of the distribution up to a given (relative) x coordinate.  We can take the cumulative sum of those values, interpolate that at the desired target points, and difference the result:

```
def resampler(orig, N):
    x = np.arange(len(orig) + 1)
    y = np.insert(orig.cumsum(), 0, 0)
    target = np.linspace(0, len(orig), N+1)
    integ = np.interp(target, xp=x, fp=y)
    result = np.diff(integ)
    return result
```

gives me

```
In [137]: x = np.array([6,4,2,4,6])

In [138]: resampler(x, 5)
Out[138]: array([ 6.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  6.])

In [139]: resampler(x, 10)
Out[139]: array([ 3.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.])

In [140]: resampler(x, 3)
Out[140]: array([ 8.66666667,  4.66666667,  8.66666667])

In [141]: resampler(x, 3).sum()
Out[141]: 22.0

In [142]: resampler(x, 20)
Out[142]: 
array([ 1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
        0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5])

In [143]: resampler(x, 13)
Out[143]: 
array([ 2.30769231,  2.30769231,  2.        ,  1.53846154,  1.53846154,
        0.92307692,  0.76923077,  0.92307692,  1.53846154,  1.53846154,
        2.        ,  2.30769231,  2.30769231])

In [144]: resampler(x, 13).sum()
Out[144]: 22.0
```

Comment: *whistle*  +1 nice!

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for, and you even helped me to figure out how to ask for it.

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, use `np.repeat`:

```
a1 = np.array([6,4,2,4,6])
targ_len = 10 #Enter target length
len_arr = len(a1)
factor = targ_len / len_arr
a2 = np.repeat(a1, factor) / factor
```

Output:

```
array([3., 3., 2., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3.])
```

Comment: Very close, and very impressive. Unfortunately I was ambiguous. The list must have the required number of items. The items do not need to be whole numbers, however.